# How is the the time complexity O(nlogn)? Am I missing something?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

I have a function for the following problem statement:

> Remove k least frequent elements to make the remaining ones as least
> unique ints set.

How is the Time Complexity O(nlogn)? I am calculating O(n + nlogn).

```
public class KRemoval {
    public static int solution(int k, ArrayList<Integer> arr, int num) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
        for (int a : arr)
            map.put(a, map.getOrDefault(a, 0) + 1);

        PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue((a, b) -> map.get(a) - map.get(b));
        for (int key : map.keySet())
            q.offer(key);

        while (k > 0 && !q.isEmpty())
            k -= map.get(q.poll());

        return k < 0 ? q.size() + 1 : q.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: O(n + n log n) *is* O(n log n).

Comment: (Because as n increases the n*log n term becomes much larger than the n term)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thank you so much for the clarification. I understand it better now.

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you so much for the clarification. I understand it better now.

Comment: You guys may post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`n + n*log(n)` can be seen as the sum of two distinct functions, that are `f(n) = n` and `g(n) = n*log(n)`, respectively. The first function is slower than the second, since the limit `lim_{n -> +inf}{f(n) / g(n)}` tends to zero.

Therefore, asymptotically (i.e. when you "move" towards the infinite), the first function does not really influence the behavior of the total function, which will strictly depend on the behavior of `n*log(n)`. Thus, we say the cost is `O(n*log(n))`.